# .htaccess rewrite in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting

I am currently deploying a number of sites from one hosting account. I have all of the sites in their own folder including the primary domain. The issue I have is when I rewrite the primary domains address with my current code, it includes the subdirectory in it. So currently if I type in `http://www.example.com/url` it rewrites to `https://example.com/folder/url`. I just want it to rewrite without the folder.

Any ideas. I know I am complicating this by running my primary domain in a subdirectory, just trying to clean up hosting as best as possible.

In my `public_html` `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/index.php [L]
```

and in `public_html/folder` `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So currently if I type in `http://www.site.whatever/url` it *rewrites* to `https://site.whatever/folder/url`.

This is a "redirect", not a rewrite.

This is happening because of the use of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in your HTTP to HTTPS redirect in your `public_html/folder` `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path of the request, which, by the time the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file is called, has been updated to contain `/folder`.

You need to either:

- Move your canonical www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS redirects to the `.htaccess` file in the document root. (This would be preferable if you have no other mod_rewrite directives in your `public_html/folder` `.htaccess` file.)

OR,

- Modify the above directive to use the `$1` backreference (to the captured `RewriteRule` *pattern*) as you are doing in the preceding www to non-www redirect. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

  (Note that this should ultimately be a 301 redirect, once you have confirmed it works OK.)

And don't forget to escape literal dots in the regex.

Comment: Thanks, I did implement a few changes you suggested and it is now working for me.

Comment: @MrWhite: Why `(.*)` instead of `^(.*)$`? And does `$1` match the entire capture group (meaning the entire URL) or just the path after the host?

Comment: @Robusto The regex `(.*)` and `^(.*)$` are the same, because regex is greedy by default. `(.*)` is a bit shorter and cleaner IMO (although some do prefer using the anchors). `$1` does match the "entire captured group", however, that is not the "entire URL". The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ only matches against the URL-path (less the slash prefix) - so this excludes the _host_ and query string. eg. Given the full URL `https://example.com/foo/bar/baz?a=1&b=2`, the URL-path contained in the `$1` backreference (in the above example) is `foo/bar/baz` (no slash prefix).

Comment: @Robusto My comment above, regarding the `$1` backreference is assuming the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root. If the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory (as discussed in this question) then the `$1` backreference will not contain that subdirectory becuase the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path _less the directory-prefix_. So, if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/foo` subdirectory (from my example in the comment above) then `$1` would contain `bar/baz` (not `foo/bar/baz`).

Comment: @MrWhite: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. I have this rewrite rule similar to yours (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`) and it works on the root and most subdirectories, but on one subdir it gives a 404 error. None of the subdir .htaccess files has any rewrite rules. Any thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: @Robusto Does the redirect occur? What is your redirect doing?

Comment: @MrWhite: Turns out fixing permissions and clearing the server cache solved the problem. Thanks for your help.